# OCamlfind local library unbound module

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

I am trying to use ocamlfind to install a [library](https://github.com/eatonphil/owebl). I am using OCamlMakeFile. Here is my Makefile:

```
OCAMLMAKEFILE = OCamlMakeFile

RESULT = owebl
SOURCES = src/utils.ml src/verb.ml src/request.ml src/template.ml src/response.ml src/rule.ml src/handler.ml src/server.ml
PACKS = unix str

all: native-code-library byte-code-library
install: libinstall
uninstall: libuninstall

include $(OCAMLMAKEFILE)
```

So basically the library is a collection of modules that I want to distribute. A basic usage of the library is (main.ml):

```
open Response
open Rule
open Verb
open Server

let handler =
    Handler.create
        (StaticRouteRule.create "/" [GET])
        (FileResponse.create
            ~static_file:(FileResponse.StaticFile "/index.html")
            ())

let server = Server.create "0.0.0.0" 8080 [handler];;

server#serve
```

I compile the library just by running "make". It generates three files: "owebl.a, owebl.cma, owebl.cmxa". Then I install the library using ocamlfind:

```
ocamlfind install owebl META owebl.a owebl.cma owebl.cmxa
```

Oh, the META file is:

```
version = "0.1"
name = "OWebl"
description = "A Web Framework for OCaml"
archive(byte) = "owebl.cma"
archive(native) = "owebl.cmxa"
requires = "unix,str"
```

Everything works until I try to compile the above example that uses the library. I run:

```
ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -pkgs owebl main.native
```

And I get:

```
ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -pkgs owebl main.native
+ ocamlfind ocamlc -c -package owebl -o main.cmo main.ml
File "main.ml", line 1, characters 5-10:
Error: Unbound module Owebl
Command exited with code 2.
Hint: Recursive traversal of subdirectories was not enabled for this build,
  as the working directory does not look like an ocamlbuild project (no
  '_tags' or 'myocamlbuild.ml' file). If you have modules in subdirectories,
  you should add the option "-r" or create an empty '_tags' file.

  To enable recursive traversal for some subdirectories only, you can use the
  following '_tags' file:

      true: -traverse
      <dir1> or <dir2>: traverse

Compilation unsuccessful after building 2 targets (1 cached) in 00:00:00.
make: *** [fileserver] Error 10
```

I tried adding `open Owebl` to the beginning of main.ml but I just got "unbound module Owebl" similarly. I'm pretty lost as to why these modules are all unbound. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `LIB_PACK_NAME` variable if you want to pack your modules under umbrella namespace, like `OWebl`, otherwise they will be available just as it is, e.g. `Response`, `Rule`, etc. Also, you should specify the `mli` files as well as `ml` files in `SOURCES` variable. And finally, you shouldn't forget to install `cmi` files, as well as `.a` files. Installing `mli` files is also considered a good tradition, although is not strictly required. Also, consider using `OCamlMakefile` installation facilities instead of custom installation script.

Answer (score 0):

I am no longer using OCamlMakefile therefore am not sure, but assuming OCamlMakefile compiles things with `-for-pack OWebl` option and properly builds a packaged module `owebl.cmo`, you also need to install `owebl.cmi`.

OCaml compiler seeks `cmi` files to check the existence of modules and to get their type information. If not installed, the compiler cannot find it. `cma` and `cmxa` files are collections of objects and do not provide type information.